I cannot post answers
Reputation points are required to comment, post answers and vote.
But reputation points are primarily gained by comments, answers being voted up, and by questions being voted up.  These leave the only way to answer a question is to ask questions first.
Yet Help says:

"The three most important activities on Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange are Asking, Answering and Editing - none of which require any reputation at all!"
https://android.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation

In addition, I have other stack exchange accounts that are connected that do have reputation points, yet apparently, I still cannot post an answer in this forum until I ask questions and get the questions voted up on this specific sub-forum.
This seems like way too many hoops for someone to jump through just to share knowledge that they may have to help someone else.  Am I missing something here? Is this site broken for my account?  Is there another way to post answers?
I have searched for answers to this on this site, general internet searches, and within settings questions answered.  I have no idea how to proceed.  It has bothered me for years, and on this particular android forum I have actually been a member for over 4.5 yrs and I still cannot vote, comment or answer questions!  Yet I can dramatically improve an answer to a specific question I also had because posted solutions didn't work in my case.

First of all, welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange!
I'd assume the question in question is Accidentally turned on TalkBack, how do I turn it off?. As mentioned on the banner, the question was automatically protected because it gathered (now deleted) low-quality answers, or even posts that are not really solving the question, and thus a minimum reputation of 10 is needed to post an answer.
The restriction is kind of unfortunate but sometimes needed because new users may not be familiar with how this site works as a Q&A site, where "Answer" is only for answering the question (i.e. not for asking clarification, mentioning they have the same problem, etc.) and instead treat it like a discussion forum where they can post almost anything.
I now have unprotected the question so that anyone (including you) can post an answer to that question. Meanwhile, since your question is exactly the same as the duplicate, I had to close your question as a duplicate, but also merge it so that your answer was automatically moved there. No need to post another answer there! But you can still edit your answer :)

As for the reputation boost, there is a site association bonus rep of +100 when users joining a different Stack Exchange site. However, this requires the user to have at least 200 reps in 1 site first.

Sorry for the rough beginning. Hopefully, you can understand the reasoning, and also looking forward to your future contribution.

Yes that is it. Thank you for all the details and for taking care of the merge and posting.  I am not sure I agree with the rules based on the absence of this in other forums I use more frequently, but is helpful to at least understand the line of reasoning.  It seems to me that selecting answers and voting scores helps the users identify the probability of answers being low quality or high quality but perhaps it doesn't work in all situations...
